# Need help on scripting to add the numbers

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Given a file of the form (you can use `/etc/passwd`):

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/sh
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/bin/sh
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/bin/sh
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/bin/sh
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/bin/sh
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/bin/sh
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/bin/sh
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/bin/sh
```

Needs seperating the third column and add them all

Comment: Looks like an assignment. Is this homework?

Comment: no external command? why?

Comment: Yes its a part of my assignment

Comment: I tried doing with awk

Comment: as a hint, look up `IFS` and `read` which should help you to write this without needing to rely on `awk`, which would be considered an external command.

Comment: is that `no external command` a requirement? `awk` doesn't count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat /etc/passwd | (IFS=: ; accu=0; while read login pw uid gid home shell; do let accu+=$uid; done; echo "accu=$accu")
```

Some explanation.
The builtin command read used IFS to cut line into words
The parenthesis are to modify IFS in a subshell (no side effect).

Comment: It's homework - it's better not to answer the question but to guide the OP to find the solution on their own.

Comment: I dont know anything in powershell,please help me out

Comment: yes Petesh,I am working as a system admin and now I started to work on scripts,very new to scripting.SO just getting learning from written script first.Please help me out on this power shell.

Comment: @Dumsee search for a question related to this, or, if you can't find one, ask another question in relation to powershell. We can't answer the question in the comments

Comment: About Powershell, it's another question. So please post a new question elsewhere.

Comment: @Petesh, you're right. The next time I will give tips, not a solution.